# XSLT help - transform attributes to elements and rename elements

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm an XSLT newbie and am trying to transform the following XML to the next XML.  I've commented significant changes needed in the second XML.

There are 2 major changes:

1) Since node2 element name repeats, I want to rename the second occurrence.
2) I want itemName attributes to each become an Element.
2a) For the [Customer ID] itemValue, I'll need it to be renamed 'CustomerID' when transformed to an Element.

In summary, I want the original to be transformed to a more table-like, columnar structure after being rendered in the browser.

```
<requestStatus>
<node1>
    <clientId>4634</clientId>
    <affiliateId>0</affiliateId>
    <contactId>144756</contactId>
    <requestId>64086</requestId>
    <transNumber>F27A6A65</transNumber>
    <status>11</status>
    <paymentType>D</paymentType>
    <amount>1.99</amount>
    <contactEmail>fmaraicar@linked2pay.com</contactEmail>
    <templateName>Payment Form 2</templateName>
    <createdBy>0</createdBy>
    <paymentCnt>1</paymentCnt>
    <nextPaymtDate/>
    <recurringFrequency/>
    <maxPayments>0</maxPayments>
    <untilDate/>
    <node2>
        <node2>
            <paymtId>56991</paymtId>
            <paidAmount>1.99</paidAmount>
            <paymentMethod>C</paymentMethod>
            <paymentSeq>1</paymentSeq>
            <submissionDate>08/04/2016</submissionDate>
            <creditCardType>V</creditCardType>
            <creditCardNumber>1111</creditCardNumber>
            <cardHolder>Ronald McDonald</cardHolder>
            <expirationMonth>1</expirationMonth>
            <expirationYear>2017</expirationYear>
            <achRequestId>0</achRequestId>
            <accountNumber/>
            <accountType/>
            <depositType/>
            <achSubmissionDate/>
            <achEffectiveDate/>
        </node2>
    </node2>
    <node3>
        <node4>
            <itemName>[FirstName]</itemName>
            <itemValue>Ronald</itemValue>
        </node4>
        <node4>
            <itemName>[LastName]</itemName>
            <itemValue>McDonald</itemValue>
        </node4>
        <node4>
            <itemName>[Email]</itemName>
            <itemValue>fmaraicar@linked2pay.com</itemValue>
        </node4>
        <node4>
            <itemName>[Amount]</itemName>
            <itemValue>1.99</itemValue>
        </node4>
        <node4>
            <itemName>Customer ID</itemName>
            <itemValue>CUSTOMER1</itemValue>
        </node4>
        <node4>
            <itemName>Invoice Numbers</itemName>
            <itemValue>INV10001,INV10002</itemValue>
        </node4>
    </node3>
</node1>
</requestStatus>


    To this:

<requestStatus>
<node1>
    <clientId>4634</clientId>
    <affiliateId>0</affiliateId>
    <contactId>144756</contactId>
    <requestId>64086</requestId>
    <transNumber>F27A6A65</transNumber>
    <status>11</status>
    <paymentType>D</paymentType>
    <amount>1.99</amount>
    <contactEmail>fMcDonald@somewhere.com</contactEmail>
    <templateName>Payment Form 2</templateName>
    <createdBy>0</createdBy>
    <paymentCnt>1</paymentCnt>
    <nextPaymtDate/>
    <recurringFrequency/>
    <maxPayments>0</maxPayments>
    <untilDate/>
    <node2>
        <node2b>   <!-- since node2 element was repeated, rename this as node2b -->
            <paymtId>56991</paymtId>
            <paidAmount>1.99</paidAmount>
            <paymentMethod>C</paymentMethod>
            <paymentSeq>1</paymentSeq>
            <submissionDate>08/04/2016</submissionDate>
            <creditCardType>V</creditCardType>
            <creditCardNumber>1111</creditCardNumber>
            <cardHolder>Ronald McDonald</cardHolder>
            <expirationMonth>1</expirationMonth>
            <expirationYear>2017</expirationYear>
            <achRequestId>0</achRequestId>
            <accountNumber/>
            <accountType/>
            <depositType/>
            <achSubmissionDate/>
            <achEffectiveDate/>
        </node2b>   
    </node2>
    <node3>  
        <FirstName>Ronald</FirstName>  <!-- each itemName attribute to become a unique Element -->
        <LastName>McDonald</LastName>
        <Email>fMcDonald@somewhere.com</Email>
        <Amount>1.99</Amount>
        <CustomerID>CUSTOMER1</CustomerID>  
        <InvoiceNumbers>INV10001,INV10002</InvoiceNumbers>
    </node3>
</node1>
```

Comment: You don't want numbered node names, you seriously don't. Reconsider your layout.

Comment: The actual XML won't - just numbered it temporarily for ease of visibility.

Comment: I disrecommend that, too. People will write solutions for numbered elements without any benefit - and your XML is not that hard to follow either way.

Answer (score 1):

I am not entirely sure of your precise requirements, but in situations like this where you are only transforming a portion of the XML, it is usually best to start with the [identity transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_transform)

```
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
```

Then, you only need to write templates for the nodes you wish to transform. So, for example, to rename the `node2` to `node2b` you would do this...

```
    <xsl:template match="node2/node2">
        <node2b>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </node2b>
    </xsl:template>
```

The `node2/node2` match ensures only the child `node2` is matched, not the parent. Replace these with your actual element names, of course.

For the `node4` elements, you can use the `xsl:element` element, together with Attribute Value Templates to create new elements, based on another value

```
  <xsl:element name="{translate(itemName, '[] ', '')}">
      <xsl:value-of select="itemValue" />
  </xsl:element>
```

The `translate` function here will strip out the specified symbols from the name. Do not that `itemName` is an element, not an attribute.

Try this XSLT as starters:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="node2/node2">
        <node2b>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </node2b>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="node4">
        <xsl:element name="{translate(itemName, '[] ', '')}">
            <xsl:value-of select="itemValue" />
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```